# Tkinter custom class error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, toplevel

I've been trying to make a class named **vwin** which makes either a Tk or Toplevel window. Unfortunately it returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RELIC\Desktop\textpad.py", line 17, in <module>
    sub = vwin(['Sub Window','640x480-25-25','normal','window'],root)
  File "C:\Users\RELIC\Desktop\textpad.py", line 9, in __init__
    window = Toplevel(master)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2136, in __init__
    BaseWidget.__init__(self, master, 'toplevel', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2086, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2064, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'vwin' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Here is my code:

```
###############################################################################
from tkinter import *

class vwin():
    def __init__(self,args,master=None):
        if args[3].lower() == 'tk':
            window = Tk()
        else:
            window = Toplevel(master)
        window.title(args[0])
        window.geometry(args[1])
        window.state(args[2])



root = vwin(['Main Window','640x480+25+25','normal','Tk'])
sub = vwin(['Sub Window','640x480-25-25','normal','window'],root)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see lots of issues.

1. In your custom class, you are just creating the `Tk()` object and assigning it to local variable `window` whose scope ends once the the `__init__()` function ends , and is most probably garbage collected. You should save the `Tk()` object as an instance variable.
2. You are sending in object of type `vwin` as master to `Sub window` vwin constructor. And then you are trying to call `Toplevel()` on the `vwin` object , which would not work. You need to use the previously saved `Tk()` object there.
3. You are never starting the mainloop() for `Tk()` so when you run the program as a script, it would end before it starts.

I think there may be tons of better way to do this , but one way to get it working for you is -

```
from tkinter import *

class vwin():
    def __init__(self,args,master=None):
        if args[3].lower() == 'tk':
            self.window = Tk()
        else:
            self.window = Toplevel(master.window)
        self.window.title(args[0])
        self.window.geometry(args[1])
        self.window.state(args[2])

    def mainloop(self):
        self.window.mainloop()



root = vwin(['Main Window','640x480+25+25','normal','Tk'])
sub = vwin(['Sub Window','640x480-25-25','normal','window'],root)
root.mainloop()
```